# CSS inserted in document head and not iframe head

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, iframe, sass

I am using the following main packages:

1. `react-frame-component` package to load my app in an iframe
2. `antd` for UI components
3. `webpack` for the build

**webpack.config.js**

```js
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = () => {
  return {
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    mode: "development",
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
      filename: "script.js",
    },
    devServer: {
      contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "build"),
      historyApiFallback: true,
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: ["babel-loader"],
        },
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
        },
      ],
    },
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: "./src/index.html",
      }),
    ],
  };
};
```

**src/index.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Frame from "react-frame-component";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Frame>
    <AppWithAntDesign />
  </Frame>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

**src/App.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import { Card, Button } from "antd";
import "./App.scss";

const App = () => (
  <Card>
    <Button>Antd</Button>
    <button className="custom-button">Normal CSS</button>
  </Card>
);

export default App;
```

**src/App.scss**

```css
.custom-button {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

When the app is rendered without the `Frame`, all the CSS referenced inside the codebase work fine, but once it's rendered as part of the `Frame` the antd CSS and local CSS do no load inside iframe's head.

PS: I do not want to know the hack to copy CSS from parent document and paste it inside iframe head.

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind is the fact styles are getting injected into parent document head element and have no effect on iframes. You need to inject styles into your iframe using StyleProvider.

This worked for me:

```
import { StyleProvider } from "@ant-design/cssinjs";

const injectPlace = (document.querySelector("#iframeId"))?.contentWindow?.document?.head; // get target iframe 
<StyleProvider autoClear container={injectPlace}>
  <Card>
    <Button>Antd</Button>
    <button className="custom-button">Normal CSS</button>
  </Card>
</StyleProvider >
```